# Is there a way to scroll a react component into view without getting a DOM node?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand that I can use the ReactDOM to find the DOM node of an element and then use that node to scroll it to the top of a scroll-able container. I know querying for DOM nodes is a bit taboo if you are using react and whenever I have been tempted to use them I have always found a better way to do whatever it was I needed to do. Is there was a clever way to do this without needing the ReactDOM at all?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? scrolling, querying?

Comment: react-scroll (https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll) works great when scrolling the window. So if your layout is pretty simple it may do what you want. For complex layouts when scrolling a view with its own scrolllbar, it is unreliable.